# split string by asterisk python

Tags: python, string, pattern-matching, matching, split

I have just started learning python 2 days ago, sorry if i have made obvious mistake

```
strings: "brake  break  at * time" --> ["at","time"]
"strang  strange  I felt very *" --> ["very",""]
```

I am trying to get word before and after *

My attempt:

```
re.match(r"(?P(first_word)\w+) ('_*_') (?P(first_word)\w+)",strings).group('first_word')
```

for getting first word

```
re.match(r"(?P(first_word)\w+) ('_*_') (?P(first_word)\w+)",strings).group('last_word')
```

for getting last word

error: nothing to repeat

Comment: have you tried `.split('*')`, since it is a `*` you don't want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `string.split('*')`.

Like this(works for 1 * only):

```
>>> s = "brake  break  at * time"
>>> def my_func(s):
     parts = s.split('*')
     a = parts[0].split()[-1]
     b = parts[1].split()[0] if parts[1].split() else ''
     return a,b
>>> my_func(s)
('at', ' time')
```

Or if you want regex:

```
>>> s = "brake  break  at * time 123 * blah"
>>> regex = re.compile("(\w+)\s+\*\s*(\w*)")
# Run findall
>>> regex.findall(s)
[(u'at', u'time'), (u'123', u'blah')]
```

Comment: Yes the output is exactly what i want!! Thanks a million!

Comment: It doesn't work for this example `"strang  strange  I felt very *" --> ["very",""]`

Comment: Your first example doesn't work for `s = "brake  break  at * time foo"`

Comment: @Schoolboy Nope. `>>> s="strang  strange  I felt very *"
>>> s.split('*')[0].split()[-1],s.split('*')[1].split()[0]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#70>", line 1, in <module>
    s.split('*')[0].split()[-1],s.split('*')[1].split()[0]
IndexError: list index out of range`

Answer (score 2):

```py
import re
text1 = "brake  break  at * time"
text2 = "strang  strange  I felt very *"
compiled = re.compile(r'''
(\w+)  # one or more characters from [_0-9a-zA-Z] saved in group 1
\s+  # one or more spaces
\*  # literal *
\s*  # zero or more spaces
(\w*)  # zero or more characters from [_0-9a-zA-Z] saved in group 2
''',re.VERBOSE)

def parse(text):
    result = compiled.search(text)
    return [result.group(1), result.group(2)]

print(parse(text1))
print(parse(text2))
```

Output:

```
['at', 'time']
['very', '']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
[x.strip() for x in "test1 * test2".split('*', 1)]
```

`.strip()` gets rid off whitespaces and `.split('*', 1)` splits the string by asterisk once.

As you want only one word:

```
words = [x.strip() for x in "test1 * test2".split('*', 1)]
first = words[0].rsplit(' ', 1)[1]
last = words[1].split(' ', 1)[0]
```

Comment: although it doesn't gives the exact output but thanks for helping!

Comment: @PiotrHajduga I like this better because it doesn't use regex